# Specifying a Button Content that has mix of text and a Binding path

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

How do you specify the Content of a button that is a mix of some TEXT and a Binding path?

Like this:

```
<Button Content= "TEXT" + "{Binding Path=ButtonContent}"
```

Comment: Are you talking about `StringFormat`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Button>
   <Button.Content>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBindingPath, StringFormat='Some text {0}'}"/>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

OR

```
<Button>
   <Button.Content>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="Some Text"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeBindingPath}"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Basically, you can put any content inside a button using the approach above.

Answer (score 44):

For most cases you can use StringFormat in the Bindings, like for a `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox,
                          Path=Text,
                          StringFormat='{}{0} - Added Text'}"/>
```

However, this has no effect on a `ContentControl` (which `Button` inherits from). Instead, you can use `ContentStringFormat`

```
<Button Content="{Binding ElementName=textBox,
                          Path=Text}"
        ContentStringFormat="{}{0} - Added Text"/>
```

Also, for

- `ContentControl` you use `ContentStringFormat`
- `HeaderedContentControl` you use `HeaderStringFormat`
- `ItemsControl` you use `ItemStringFormat`

Answer (score 2):

Building on the other answers, this is a little more terse:

```
<Button Content="{Binding FirstName, StringFormat='Click here, {0}!'}" />
```